# android button listener for some combination

Tags: android

I m trying to build an app in which I want to use combination of buttons to give input and I want that when user presses multiple buttons then they can press buttons in a gap of 2 sec and then finally I want to write code for the combination of buttons. Is there any listener for this type of operation?

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so far? Please share your code. You cannot simply ask a question and get the code.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no listener Nidhi. you may create a `flag` and set it on button click and unset in a `timer`. so when user click on a button he will not be able to click other button until `timer` unset the `flag`.